# Is it possible to use Haskell on Arch Linux ARM?

Tags: archlinux, cross-compilation, arm, haskell

There isn't a ghc package for armv6, which is what the pi uses. It does not need to be able to compile on the pi, just run on it.

Comment: have you tried this sudo pacman -S ghc

Comment: Yes, it isn't in the repo for pi.

Comment: it is according to this http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=6655

Comment: @SteveRobillard That is outdated. It is no longer in the repos.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe GHC support ARM as an official platform and thus there is limited usability in ARMv5 & ARMv7 and it was not building for ARMv6.